# How to get mindate value from collection of hashmap?

Tags: java, arraylist

i have following code snippets

```
ArrayList col = [{name ="ddd",date =10/08/2011},{name ="xxxx",date =15/08/2011},....]
```

i have one arraylist that contain list of hashmap as above . In each hashmap there is key called date. Now, i want to get mindate from all dates present in list of hashmap.

for example  in above collection i should get 10/08/2011

how to do that ? 
Plz help me

Thanks In Adavance

Comment: Hm, iterate through the list and find the mindate... where's the problem?

Comment: Isn't that JavaScript? At least it's no actual Java code.

Answer (score 2):

- Start with a `null` result.
- Iterate through the list.
- get the date of the current map. If the result is `null` or if the result is bigger than the date of the current map, set the result to the date of the current map.
- after the loop, return the result

Dates can be compared with `date1.compareTo(date2)`, since `java.util.Date` implements `Comparable`.

If your dates are in fact strings representing dates, parse the string using `SimpleDateFormat`.

The javadoc is here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html

Comment: Try implementing it, and show us the code. We'll help you from there. It's pretty basic: a variable, a loop, and two if tests.